# "It needs to {be / have been} deviated for 1 minute"

Tags: passive-voice, perfect-constructions

I would like to understand the difference between these two:

> "It needs to have been deviated for 1 minute"
>   "It needs to be deviated for 1 minute"

Are both saying that the deviation needs to be occuring over time? I think that the past infinitive is just for that but on the other hand, wouldn't the other sentence mean the same?

Comment: It's not necessarily *wrong*, but this usage of transitive "to deviate [something]" is pretty unusual. Depending on the exact context, probably ***divert*** would be more suitable.

Comment: @Silkyss, is _deviate_ in this sense some technical process, perhaps in Chemistry or Engineering?

Comment: Yes, IT technical documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these expressions are ungrammatical. *Deviate* is an intransitive verb: it means to diverge from an appointed course or established value, not to cause something to diverge.

An intransitive verb cannot be cast in the passive voice. Consequently you must say:

> It needs to have deviated for one minute.  *OR*
>   It needs to deviate for one minute.

If these sentences define the circumstances under which some subsequent event is triggered, such as a correction or a warning message, there is no significant difference between them: both express the fact that action is taken after a one-minute deviation.

If this is not the case—for instance, if the deviation is actively desired in order to accomplish your purposes—then the distinction drawn by magistermurphy is operative: the sentence with the perfect construction looks to a point in time **after** the deviation, while the sentence with the simple construction looks to a point **before** the deviation.

Comment: THanks. But I think it can be cast in the passive voice like this: It needs to be deviated from the baseline ...  Would that be correct?

Comment: @Silkyss No: only transitive verbs can be cast in the passive. You cannot deviate something, so something cannot be deviated.

Comment: strange. The following sentence was written by a native speaker:  .... has been deviating from the baseline long enough and activates the system.

Comment: @Silkyss That is not a passive construction, which is built with *BE* + ***past** participle* but a **progressive** construction, built with *BE* + ***present** participle* (*-ing* form). (Specifically, it is a present perfect progressive.)

Comment: THank you very much. So even if the text is technical, I cannot say use "it needs to be deviated from ...", right

Comment: @Silkyss That is correct. We say that a value **deviates** from an established norm or standard, not that it "is deviated". You occasionally find a transitive use among 19th century scientists, but this use has not caught on and should be regarded as non-standard.

Answer (score 0):

The sentences do not mean the same thing. "It needs to be deviated for 1 minute" means that this is the next step, that it should be deviated now.

"It needs to have been deviated for 1 minute," means that it should already have happened. It means the same thing as, "Before the next step happens, the one minute of deviation must already be done."

Comment: Are you sure "It needs to **have been deviated**" is correct, grammatically?

Comment: Yes. See here under "perfect infinitive: passive." http://www.grammaring.com/the-forms-of-the-infinitive

Comment: But *deviate* is intransitive and cannot be cast in the passive.

Comment: That's true. I had assumed this was a technical use of _deviated_ and that it could be used passively in that technical sense. If that is not the case, both expressions are ungrammatical, as @StoneyB said.